# NopCommerce source code deployment shows: InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I am trying to deploy nopcommerce using the source code. But whenever I try to run it, it is showing `InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.` exception.

I researched on SO and found that this error comes when there is a parameterless constructor in the `DbContext`.

I searched all of the Nopcommerce source code but found no DBContext with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: What did you configure in your `Web.config` / `App.Config` ?

Comment: @kara I haven't touched any code. I just downloaded the source code, opened the solution file and ran it. As mentioned here: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Installation+guide

Comment: I'm not familiar with nopcommerce, but your exception is quite explicit: If you use a EF-DbContext, you have to tell your program two things: Which db should be used (client-driver)? How are they mapped to .Net components (provider)? Search for your App.config and have a look at it.

Comment: @kara the configuration file is same as https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/web.config

Comment: @AppSoln, is this error in published code? or in source code?

Comment: @AppSoln, Also which version of nop you're working with?